# Google Places API: More specific types?

Tags: google-places-api

When I Google "Justine's" I can see that it's listed as a "French Restaurant". ([See screenshot](https://dr.tt/view?d=vj7n0c7vz4wp93f%2F2016-03-21%20at%2010.59.png%2F))

When I use the Google Places API to get details about the same spot I only see a list of "types" that includes high-level terms like "restaurant" and "bar", but I see no specific types like "French Restaurant".

Does anyone know if it's possible to get this data?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the industry sector of a company with Google Places API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096690/get-the-industry-sector-of-a-company-with-google-places-api)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would probably have to check with the text search method on the api..
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

So your request would end up looking something like the below, restricted down to a specific area

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=French +Restaurant&sensor=true&location=yourLocationHere&radius=20&key=yourKeyHere

However this will return all other French restaurants in the area, so if you just want to return the one result I would use the Place Details request instead