# Get the industry sector of a company with Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get the type of industry sector a company belongs to by using the Google Places API.

For example, when I do the obligatory example search for "rhythmboat cruises pyrmont", in the information box on the right side, Google tells me that this company is a "Cruise Agency" - however I am having a hard time finding this information within the Google Places API - neither using one of the general searches nor by using the detail search.

Am I right with my assumption that Google does not provide this information via the Places API and if yes, does another Google API provide this data?

Answer (score 4):

Places API exposes several `types` for this place:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
types: [
    "travel_agency",
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
],
```

I think you can classify any place into an industry sector by these types.

At least it seems like it should work with the [4 major industry sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_industry#Industry_sectors), the broader [Global Industry Classification Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard#Sector_and_industry_group_classification.5B4.5D), or [PwC's list](http://www.pwc.com/gx/en/industries.html). Only in the 4 major industry sectors would I expect that every company fits under just one sector though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, those types do represent the type of the company in a more broader sense. Yet, I am interested in this specific business that Google lists.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a feature request for more types, i.e. a finer classification. I'd recommend you request this at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: Actually, there is one already: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5260

Comment: Thanks, i will monitor that!