# Google Places API search for only carparks (not bikeparks)

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to get parking places around a venue by using the Google Places API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.364119,4.870929&type=parking&rankby=distance&key=MYKEY.

I get back a results with parkings for cars and also with parking for bikes. I cannot find any difference in de details to make a distinction between both.

On the other hand when I lookup thise places on Google Maps it says that de car-parking is a Parking and the bike-parking is indicated as a Bikeparking.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127996/google-places-api-more-specific-types

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker. Please have a look at [issue 5260](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5260) where this problem was raised.

It looks like Google is working on it, however they don't expose any ETA.

Please star this public issue to add your vote and receive future updates from Google.